# Swift 3 type inference error in Xcode 8.2.1, in swift-style for statement

Tags: xcode, swift3

I don't know if anybody else has met this problem. I updated my Xcode to 8.2.1 today. When I tried to place several buttons on a scrollView, I found a type inference error. The core code is shown below:

```
for i in 0 ..< 6 {

        let titleButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * titleWidth, y: 0, width: titleWidth, height: titleHeight))


        sv.addSubview(titleButton)
    }
```

The code had no problem to place 6 buttons on the scrollView(sv), but when I tried to set a title for each button Using call:`setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState)` under the initialization of the button, Xcode did not show method completion suggest. I found the reason is 'titleButton' is inferred as error type by Xcode.

Then I tried:

```
for i in 0 ..< 6 {

        let frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * titleWidth, y: 0, width: titleWidth, height: titleHeight)

        let titleButton = UIButton(frame: frame)


        sv.addSubview(titleButton)
    }
```

And found 'frame' is inferred as error type, so the type inference failure of 'titleButton' seems from the frame. Finally I found that the variable 'i' from the beginning of this for statement is inferred as error type, that is the origin.

I didn't find similar problem in past Xcode versions. If I really need to use 'i' in my logic among for-loop, is there someone who has an idea to solve the inference error?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I have to indicate the type myself as follow:

```
let titleButton : UIButton = UIButton(frame: frame)
```

Then under this, the method completion suggestion works fine. Hope Apple can fix the type inference error quickly...